# What is Compile Time constant expression value inlined by compiler in JAVA?

Tags: java

Recently i was reading i got this

> "When you declare a String (which is immutable) variable as final, and
>   initialize it with a compile-time constant expression, it also becomes
>   a compile-time constant expression, and its value is inlined by the
>   compiler where it is used."

and **"i'm really confused what does this mean its value is inlined by compiler" ?** Please explain it in Simple way if possible

[Source of the above line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418427/comparing-strings-with-which-are-declared-final-in-java/19418517#19418517)

Comment: please attach link where you find specific quoted text!!!

Comment: Inling basically means "replacing the calls to the variable/method with the actual value or code contained in the method". It's a performance consideration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082971/compile-time-constants-and-variables

Comment: @JeroenVannevel How do you *call* a variable? ;-)

Comment: @Dev i've provided it at the end of the code !

Answer (score 2):

When a String is finalized and initialized at compile time, the compiler can copy-paste the string into the code, instead of looking up the variable at every use. Similar to [inline expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion).

```
final String a = "asd";
String b = a;
```

The above snippet becomes

```
final String a = "asd";
String b = "asd";
```