# How do I switch on values defined inside a java enum of strings

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I have the following code :

```
class MyClass {
    private Value value;
    public enum Value {
        INSERT_ONLY("INSERT_ONLY"), UPDATE_ONLY("UPDATE_ONLY"), UPSERT("UPSERT") ;
        private final String val ;
        private Value(final String v) {val = v ;}
        public String toString() {return val ;}     
        public String getVal() {
            return val;
        }
    } ;
    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class one {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass() ;
        obj.setValue(MyClass.Value.INSERT_ONLY) ;

        String s = obj.getValue().toString() ;
        String s1 = MyClass.Value.INSERT_ONLY.toString() ;
        switch(s) {
            case "INSERT_ONLY" : System.out.println("INSERT_ONLY") ;
                break ;
            case "s2" : System.out.println("s2") ;
                break ;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works. But what I want is that in switch-case I use the strings as defined in the `enum Value`. If I use `s1` in `case`, it generates an error. What is the way out?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? What's the error?

Comment: I want to use `s1` in `case` AND NOT in `switch`

Answer (score 1):

Enums have a method `.name()` that returns the enum as a String. All your "values" are equivalent to this - just switch on that.

You can delete the `value` field, the constructor and getter and call `name()` where you are currently calling `getValue()`.

Further, the default implementation of `toString()` returns `name()` so you can delete your `toString()` method without having any effect.

Finally, you can switch on the enum itself.

Answer (score 0):

you string in the enum is actually the same as the enumertor constants... so it is a little redundant and completely unnescessary...

try this:

```
enum Value {
    INSERT_ONLY, UPDATE_ONLY, UPSERT;
}

public static void main(String[] args)  {
Week obj = new Week() ;
Value s = obj.getValue( ) ;
        switch(s) {
            case INSERT_ONLY : System.out.println("INSERT_ONLY") ;
                break ;
            case UPDATE_ONLY : System.out.println("UPDATE_ONLY") ;
                break ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need those Strings as I have to ultimately convert the objects of  `MyClass` to-and-fro to json objects

Comment: every constant of that Enum can be printed as string if you call the method name()

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way:

```
MyClass.Value value = obj.getValue() ;
switch(value) {
  case INSERT_ONLY : System.out.println("INSERT_ONLY") ;
    break ;
  case UPSERT : System.out.println("Upsert") ;
    break ;
  case UPDATE_ONLY : System.out.println("Update only") ;
   break ;
 }
```

Basically, the switch-statement uses the enum-names. So there is no need to apply the `toString()`-method on the `Value` returned by `obj.getValue()`.

If you would like to know why switch will not work in combination with strings, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string). 
One more suggestion: add also the default-branch to the switch-statement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to look up an enum constant by an unknown string `s`. The reason your `case` expression can't be `s1` is because it must be a [compile-time constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9083023/1553851), which `s1` is not. Since your example seems to be mostly theoretical, I'll suggest a few options and you can pick the most appropriate for your actual case:

1. Assuming the enum names are the same as their `value`s (in which case you can scrap the field entirely) and you're just trying to look up an enum by its name, just do this:

   ```
   MyClass.Value v = MyClass.Value.valueOf(s);
   ```

   This will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if no mapping is found for `s1`.
2. Still assuming the names are the same, but you do need an actual `switch` with some additional cases and custom logic:

   ```
   try {
       MyClass.Value v = MyClass.Value.valueOf(s);
       switch (v) {
           case INSERT_ONLY : System.out.println("INSERT_ONLY") ;
               break ;
       }
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
       switch (s)
           case "s2" : System.out.println("s2") ;
               break ;
       }
   }
   ```
3. If the names are not actually the same, you can add a static map of constants inside the enum class, to simulate `valueOf()`:

   ```
   public enum Value {
       ONLY_INSERT("ONLY_INSE"), ONLY_UPDATE("UPDATE_ONLY"), UPSERT("UPSERT") ;

       private static final Map<String, Value> byName = new HashMap<>();
       static {
           for (Value v : values()) {
               byName.put(v.getVal(), v);
           }
       }

       public static Value byName(String name) {
           Value result = byName.get(name);
           if (result == null) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name" + name);
           }
           return result;
       }

       private final String val ;
       private Value(final String v) {val = v ;}
       public String toString() {return val ;}     
       public String getVal() {
           return val;
       }
   } ;
   ```

   Now you can do the same as the previous solutions, using `MyClass.Value.byName()`.