# Passing String to annotation in Java

Tags: java, annotations

I come up with a idea that passing a `String` literal to annotation. Is it possible in Java 8/9? If not, in what circumstances could it be needed? How can it be applied otherwise?

For example:

```
final String test = "literal";

@Component(test)
// .
// .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to be compile time constant. A `public static final String` will work, a merely `final` one won't (the enclosing scope/class means it's not compile time constant).

See also this Q/A: [Compile time constants and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082971/compile-time-constants-and-variables)