# String.format() as a constant expression

Tags: java, string.format

Is there any way I can get the expression below to evaluate as a constant expression? I am using Java 11 if that helps.

```
String.format("hello %1$s","world");
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the string "hello world" to be treated as a constant? It's not a constant, it's being interpolated at runtime.

Comment: @DaveNewton  I want to achieve this functionality at compile time ( and am not bound to String.format api). One way I know of achieving this is String x = "world"; String y = "Hello" + x; ... Here y is a constant though it uses a variable. I don't want to use this approach though since I have a lot of variables to replace and was hoping for a different solution.

Comment: What’s the ultimate problem you’re trying to solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile-time constants and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082971/compile-time-constants-and-variables)

Comment: Currently not, but see https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/348 for a potential improvementon this.

Comment: @DaveNewton Should not matter.

Comment: @AakashVerma And yet it does--if, say, the ultimate problem is doing some string replacement, this might be handled by a Maven/Gradle plugin (e.g., property file replacements). If the issue is needing string constants in a byteclass file then any of several bytecode modification tools could be used. If the issue is creating a runtime constant at runtime, then it's not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the compiler cannot treat this as compile-time constant expression (Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082971)).

To illustrate: Using bytecode manipulation, it would be possible to modify the behavior of String.format(), e.g. what is possible in unit-testing with PowerMock and similar libraries. In that case `String.format("hello %1$s","world")` could return something else than "hello world".

Note:
I assume you mean as a "compile-time constant expression". (Else you can just define a variable `final foo = String.format(...)`, and the variable foo will be a constant in the following code). But such constants cannot e.g. be used as annotation values.